# TKinter : Create a dropdown listbox with multiselection

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to create a listbox that would appear and disappear at the click of a button.

This part of the work is already done. But how to make this list over the interface like a Combobox ?

I tried to make a combobox with multiselection (below an example) but obviously as soon as I click on one of the elements it closes.

```html
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        menubutton = tk.Menubutton(self, text="Choose wisely", 
                                   indicatoron=True, borderwidth=1, relief="raised")
        menu = tk.Menu(menubutton, tearoff=False)
        menubutton.configure(menu=menu)
        menubutton.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.choices = {}
        for choice in ("Iron Man", "Superman", "Batman"):
            self.choices[choice] = tk.IntVar(value=0)
            menu.add_checkbutton(label=choice, variable=self.choices[choice], 
                                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0, 
                                 command=self.printValues)
    def printValues(self):
        for name, var in self.choices.items():
            print "%s: %s" % (name, var.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Can we multi select with optionMenu ?

Comment: Sorry, meant `Checkbutton`, but you already use it. ***as soon as I click on one of the elements it closes***: That's the intended behaviour. The behavior of checkbuttons can be changed by defining new bindings. Try `command=lambda: return 'break'.